# Load style from database in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgresql, style

Maybe it's a stupid question, but I don't know how to connect layer style with database in QGIS.

When I save the style to postgres database in QGIS, it automatically saves the style in the table layer_styles in public scheme.

But when I want to reconnect it to the layer, it shows only all other layer styles without required one and in the window 'styles related to the layer' there is a message "No styles found in the database". Do you know, where the problem could be?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: try 'use as default style for this layer' option before saving to the db

Comment: I already tried,but it doesn't work either :/

Answer (score 1):

Grant & owner problem? I just fixed a similar problem with the layer_styles by correcting the owner from user A to the user group containing users A and B.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot I see that f_table_catalog field is blank. Mine has the database name in that field & if I delete it I get the same behaviour you are describing.